# Spatial index in Berkeley DB

Tags: berkeley-db, r-tree

Does Berkeley DB have a spatial index such as R-tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's asking [the same question on the Oracle forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1119710). No Oracle answer yet. But the answer is no, it doesn't have any built-in spatial index functionality. Berkeley DB is a low-level database offering basic functionality which you can build upon. The building blocks are [Btree, Hash, Queue and Recno](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/am_conf.html#am_conf_intro). I don't doubt that a determined programmer could implement spatial indices using those. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

On some other [page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_unix_sql.html#idp50563608) however you can read that spatial indices are possible. It's because BerkeleyDB has its SQL interface binary compatible with SQLite's interface so you can use anything which is built on top of that. SQLite's R*-trees and full text search are just two examples.